# Error in Firebase iOS Codelab Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, firebase

How would I go about fixing this error? I am fairly new to Swift development.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please Add code instead of image.

Comment: Ah I apologize, I just figured the error out but I'll do this next time I have an error.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:
`let config = FIRRemoteCongig.remoteConfig()`

Comment: This corrected the aforementioned error but leads to me getting "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)" on the final line.

Comment: Aha, I fixed it using "remoteConfig = FIRRemoteConfig.remoteConfig()". Thank you for leading me to this!